# Select columns with specific value (Dummy Table)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question on SQL Server, I want to write a query that has no related need with its `FROM`.

I want to `SELECT` with result that create view table and assigned values.
For ease of understanding let say I want to make a view table that have 2 columns (`key` and `value`):

```
+-------+-----------+
|KEY    |   Value   |
+-------+-----------+
|A      |   15      |
|B      |   16      |
|C      |   17      |
|D      |   18      |
|E      |   19      |
+-------+-----------+
```

all of the value are from the query itself, not from the table.

My Query is:

```
SELECT ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E') AS KEY,
       (15, 16, 17, 18, 19) AS Value
FROM
    t1 ---- table doesn't matter
```

How to utilize the `SELECT` clause to reach it?

Comment: I have no idea what you're after here. You can't use tuples in the `SELECT` like that. Are you asking about the `VALUES` operator? [Table Value Constructor (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: In SQL `SELECT` only *selects* data. It doesn't create it. That's the job of the `FROM` clause. Talking about `SELECT` causes confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to create a "dummy" table and use it in the `WHERE` clause the same way you would use any other table :

```
select myTable.*
from 
( values ('A',15),
         ('B',16)) myTable([key],value)
```

`key` must be quoted because it's a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Pivot` query

```
select *
from 
(
  select Keys, Value
  from #yt
) src
pivot
(
  min(Value)
  for keys in ([A], [B], [C], [D], [E])
) piv;
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f3286ad8bb488c4d8b02dc265c109714)**